# Join de dos DataTable para obtener sólo lo de Tabla A

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

En VB.Net, tengo dos `DataTable` (`A` y `B`; sólo tienen un campo `Int32`) y necesito obtener exclusivamente lo que está en `A` y no en `B`.

¿Cuál sería la manera óptima de hacerlo? Estuve leyendo ejemplos con LINQ pero no di pie con bola.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos lo que intentaste para decirte como resolver el problema?

Comment: Muchas gracias a Leandro por la respuesta y al resto por indicarme cómo preguntar mejor. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias implementar el `left join` de linq

[How to: Combine Data with LINQ by Using Joins (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx)

analiza el titulo `Perform a Left Outer Join by Using the Group Join Clause`

Podria ser algo como

```
Dim result As List(Of A) = (From a In dtA.AsEnumerable()
                           Group Join b In dtB.AsEnumerable() On a.Field(Of Integer)("nombrecampo") equals b.Field(Of Integer)("nombrecampo") Into list = Group
                           Where list.DefaultIfEmpty() IsNot Nothing
                           Select a).ToList()
```